# Get Target Ip Address From SNMP4j Trap Receiver

Tags: java, snmp, net-snmp, snmp4j, snmp-trap

I create snmp trap receiver using snmp4j. I managed to receive the pdu and process it. I need the targeted ip address as my machine have multiple ip addresses. I could thinking either two ways:

1. Retrieve entire command in my trap receiver which is "snmpset -v 1 -c M xx.xxx.x.x 1.3.6.1.4.1.161.3.6.37.2.1.3.2 i 2" so that I can get the ip address by removing other strings." But the only thing I could retrieve is only the variable, value and pdu type.
2. Using method to retrieve the targeted ip address. But couldn't find one. I used `event.getTransportMapping().getListenAddress()` but getting 0.0.0.0/161 as I need to listen to many ip address. Used `event.getPeerAddress()` but getting ip address of the sender's machine.

Really appreciate for any kind of help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by:

```
UdpAddress udpHostAdress = (UdpAddress) cmdRespEvent.getTransportMapping().getListenAddress();
String ipAdd = udpHostAdress.getInetAddress().getHostAddress();
System.out.println("Target IP = " + ipAdd);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to handle security of the trap receiver, you are wrong here use snmp v3 to handle this. v3 has security mechanism called Engine ID.